# Zend 2 Console + rendering templates?

Tags: php, console, zend-framework2, rendering

I'm using the Zend console to daemonize some services (like sending emails) but I need to render them via phtml templates.
This templates use the url (view helper) and it's not working via the Zend console :

```
======================================================================
The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException
Request URI has not been set
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because via the console, there is no URI set like an HTTP request...
Is there a clean/easy way to do this ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is possible, but there are some hoops you have to jump through. How are you rendering the templates at the moment?

Comment: I have an HTTP route, so my template is correctly rendering via an url. I just wanted to replace this HTTP route by a Console route. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple patch when Zend Console is used:

- During routing, retrieve the HttpRouter, if getRequestURI() is not set, then create one and set it.